# Как получить индексы по i и j элемента, зная его номер?

Tags: матрицы, любой-язык

У меня есть матрица NxM и мне известен порядковый номер элемента при перечислении слева направо, сверху вниз.

По какой формуле я могу вычислить его индексы i,j в матрице?
Индексация начинается с 0.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, наверное, глупый...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нумерация начинается с 1, а индексы с 0, то примерно так:

```
i = int((num - 1) / N) // целая часть от деления номер-1 на количество столбцов
j = (num - 1) % N // остаток от такого деления
```

или

```
j = num - N*i - 1
```

Если индексы начинаются с единицы,то нужно сделать соответствующую поправку.

Comment: Может, и на М. Смотря что М, а что  N.

Comment: N-высота, M-ширина

Comment: Тогда М. На количество столбцов (см. комментарий в коде).

Comment: Что-то J у меня J не выводится по вашей формуле. 7/3=2.3. Остаток 3. Или я туплю...

Comment: Остаток от деления 7 на 3 равен 1.

Comment: Да, точно. Тогда по формуле разве не нужно вычесть еще единицу?

Comment: Может быть и нужно. Я ж не знаю, с нуля у вас там начинается или с единицы. Я ж написал все.

Comment: Ну вот, например у меня начинается 0 индексация. 7/3=2 ок, 8/3=2 ок, 9/3= 3 не ок.

Comment: дополнил ответ.

Comment: Да, все четко..

Comment: А если индексация начинается с 1, то как я понимаю, нужно при поиске i делать округление в большую сторону, а при подсчете j проверять, что если оно равно 0, то значит j=N?

Comment: Просто прибавить единицу к результату.